# Having trouble getting a negative answer

Tags: c++

Hey guys I'm brand new to C++ and I'm having trouble with an equation to change degrees Fahrenheit to degrees Celsius.

```
// Fahrenheit -> Celcius
if (c==1) {
    cout << "\nPlease give the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ";

    cin >> fah;

    cel=(5/9)*(fah-32);

    cout << "\n" << fah << " degrees Fahrenheit corresponds to " << cel << " degrees Celcius.";
}
```

When I put in a value for fah below 32, my answer in degrees celcius comes back as -0. How can I get a value below 0 for my answer? Btw I used float for all of my variables.

Comment: Examine each part of this code in detail.

Comment: Don't use integer arithmetic when you should be using floating point.

Comment: @DavidHammen Do compilers warn on integer division? I feel like they should =/

Comment: @Nabla The OP is just noticing it failing in that case - the conversion will be wrong for all values of F that are not 32. I suspect that `fah` is a float/double so `(0 * anyFiniteNegativeFloat) -> -0f`

Comment: @Borgleader Why would they?  It is a valid operation, and introducing a warning would simply give spurious warnings when you actually intend to do integer division.

Comment: It actually will give `0` (either `0` or `-0`) in all cases as written.

Comment: Change 5/9 ==> 5/9.f which will give floating point negative values to print.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`5/9` is integer arithmetic and, therefore, equals 0.

Try `(5.0/9)` instead to encourage the compiler to use floating point.  Alternatively, use `(5.f/9)`.

Comment: `5f` is not a floating point literal - [see here](http://ideone.com/0JJLvW). The decimal point is needed - `5.f`.

Comment: @Angew - Thanks, I thought I had put that in by mistake and didn't notice until later that you had edited my comment.  I'll put it back.  I was a C programmer and managed to skip C++ somehow.  I expected (wrongly) that this syntax hadn't changed.

Comment: Have the upvote back :-) BTW, [it doesn't seem to be legal C either.](http://ideone.com/lvpgwg)

Comment: Prefer to perform multiplication before division:  5 * (fah - 32) / 9.0.  This helps reduce floating point inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're inadvertantly converting to integer - so your fractions will get truncated.

SUGGESTED CHANGE:

```
if (c==1) {
    cout << "\nPlease give the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ";
    cin >> fah;
    cel=(5.0/9.0)*(fah-32.0);
    cout << "\n" << fah << " degrees Fahrenheit corresponds to " << cel << " degrees Celcius.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using double instead of int to allow good decimal results not every conversion is one for one

edit: Try changing your 5/9 to a decimal but, copy this code over for referance I set your variable "C" to 1 just so I didnt have to change your original code too much. These arent the most accepted coding practices but its an answer to your question.

```
// test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double c=1;
double fah=0;
double cel=0;

// Fahrenheit -> Celcius
if (c==1) {
cout << "\nPlease give the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ";

cin >> fah;

cel=(.5556)*(fah-32);

cout << setprecision(3)<<"\n" << fah << " degrees Fahrenheit corresponds to " << cel << "    degrees Celcius.";
}//endif
system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Since when does `int` not allow negative results?

Comment: your completely right I prefer using doubles for decimal results Will edit answer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using `float` for this ... unless he really needs the precision of more than 5 decimal places (doubtful).

Comment: I figured since he was new to C++, as am I he would be interested in seeing how to manipulate decimals. My answer is from the prespective of somebody who is almost on the same level as he is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also type-cast (5/9) to a float operation. It can be written as ((float)5/9). That should solve your problem.

Comment: Since this is a literal in his current code, this is the least preferred method.  If you are dealing with a literal and expect it to be of a certain type, then declare a literal of that type ... don't convert it.